# Accessing data stored in Php array in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, file-read

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting PHP array into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915058/inserting-php-array-into-javascript-array)

I'm reading a file in server with php and storing the file content in a variable. now i want to access the variable with javascript, Since I need to split the contents with tab delimited and add the content as options to a Select tag.

```
               <?php
                       //read the 'file' content to lines variable
                       $lines = file('file');
                ?>
```

Javascript to access the PHP variable($lines):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function readData(){
        var s = '<? echo $lines ?>';
        alert(s);
        }
</script>
```

Where alert pops up only with **Array** text

What Should I do so that the data stored in $lines array will be accessed in javascript array variable

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php could be a place to start

Comment: It's also not clear as to when and how your JavaScript is to execute.

Comment: How were you even allowed to ask this FAQ?

Comment: @Shamim the Js function is called on HTML button click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents('file')` instead of `file('file')` is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

`file` function is to use get file contents in an array and then iterate (say in foreach) line by line.like:

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
```

You can use `file_get_contents()` to return the contents of a file as a string. like

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

if you are using contents in JS, you 'll have to take care of special characters like quotes.